# Views Bulk Operations Checkboxes check on click

Tags: 7, views

I do search for a specific option in bulk operations. For now, when I click somewhere in my row, the checkbox for the bulk operation gets selected, but I want a user to directly click on the checkbox. If he clicks somewhere in the row, it shouldn't select the row for bulk-operations. Any chance to do that without hacking the core?

In short: only a direct click on the checkbox should select the row for bulk operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the **JQuery** in `views_bulk_operation.js` :

```
    // Set up the ability to click anywhere on the row to select it.
$('.views-table tbody tr', form).click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input' && event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
    $('input[id^="edit-views-bulk-operations"]:not(:disabled)', this).each(function() {
      var checked = this.checked;
      // trigger() toggles the checkmark *after* the event is set,
      // whereas manually clicking the checkbox toggles it *beforehand*.
      // that's why we manually set the checkmark first, then trigger the
      // event (so that listeners get notified), then re-set the checkmark
      // which the trigger will have toggled. yuck!
      this.checked = !checked;
      $(this).trigger('click');
      this.checked = !checked;
    });
  }
});
```

- Commenting them will solve it but instead of hacking the core. In your custom js file add something like:

> ```
> $('.views-table tbody tr').off();
> ```

- This will disable all event handlers!!